# Plotting mutiple graph in one graph in R with using function

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a graph in one plot only. I have 4 different plots coming by using a function. This is my code:

```
hazard.plot.w2p(beta = beta.spreda, eta = eta.spreda, time = exa1.dat$time, line.colour = "blue")
hazard.plot.w2p(beta = 1.076429, eta = 26.21113, time = exa1.dat$time, line.colour = "blue")
hazard.plot.w2p(beta = 5, eta = 32.97954, time = exa1.dat$time, line.colour = "blue")
hazard.plot.w2p(beta = 2, eta = 32.9795, time = exa1.dat$time, line.colour = "blue")
```

Here is a function i used to get output:

```
hazard.plot.w2p <- function(beta, eta, time, line.colour, nincr = 500) {
  max.time <- max(time, na.rm = F)
  t <- seq(0, max.time, length.out = nincr)
  r <- numeric(length(t))
  for (i in 1:length(t)) {
    r[i] <- failure.rate.w2p(beta, eta, t[i])
  }
  plot(t, r, type = 'l', bty = 'l', 
       col = line.colour, lwd = 2, 
       main = "", xlab = "Time", 
       ylab = "Failure rate", 
       las = 1, adj = 0.5, 
       cex.axis = 0.85, cex.lab = 1.2)
}
```

I want to plot all the 4 plots in one plot only.

Here is a sample data set:

```
fail       time
a          4.55
a          4.65
a          5.21
b          3.21
a          1.21
a          5.65
a          7.12
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data? Are they all line plots?

Comment: Sample Data Set:  
x         time
a         4.5097
a          4.235
a          4.68
a          5.55
b           3.25
a           4.55
a          4.26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `par(new=TRUE)` after each plot. Or, you can put it at the end of the function.